# Visualizing a medium size graph in python

Tags: python, graph, networkx, graphviz

I have a medium sized graph with ~400 nodes and ~6000 edges that I am trying to visualize via python. At the moment I am trying to use networkx and this is the output.

[image: badgraph]

There's 2 issues:

1. The layout seems to be too dense and I can't make out any of the edges near the center of the graph
2. There's a set of nodes that are semi-bipartite (they have no edges within themselves), and I would like to place these nodes on a vertical line on the right, and all the other nodes on the left. I can't figure out how to manage this with networkx.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: With an average of 30 edges/node (each edge connects to two) it will be quite difficult to produce a readable graph.  Sharing your source would help.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you experiment with different engines other that `dot`. Consider `neato`, `twopi` or `circo`. The [gallery section](https://graphviz.org/gallery/) on the official graphviz site has really nice examples ([300+ nodes](https://graphviz.org/Gallery/twopi/twopi2.html)) that you can mimic.